# XSD Accepting some children 0 or 1 times, and some children N times

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I have been trying to validate an XML grammar which has:

```
<Parent>
 <OptionalChild1/>
 <OptionalChild2/>
 <OptionalChild3/>
 <RepeatedChild/>
 <RepeatedChild/>
 <RepeatedChild/>
</Parent>
```

In other words, there are several elements which can be missing or present once (OptionalChild1, 2, 3) and another element which can be missing, or present once or many times.

**All child elements should be able to appear in any order**. (Except: if it helped make the XSD more possible, we could enforce that the RepeatedChild elements come after the optional ones).

I can't see any XSD schema to validate this. `xsd:all` would work for the first group, and maybe `xsd:choice` for the second group, but there's no combination I can find to enforce both rules within the parent.

Answer (score 2):

You can attach a minimum and maximum bound to element declarations.

For example, in your parent element declaration, include something like this:

```
<xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="OptionalChild1" minOccurs="0" />
   <xsd:element name="OptionalChild2" minOccurs="0" />
   <xsd:element name="OptionalChild3" minOccurs="0" />
   <xsd:element name="RepeatedChild" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xsd:sequence>
```

Note: I don't have access to a schema validator right now, but this is approximately what you want.

Comment: Yes, I always mix the two up. Thanks for that.

Comment: As long as OP is ok with an ordering on the `OptionalChild` elements, this looks good.

Comment: Sorry, but one of the key requirements is "All child elements should be able to appear in any order" as in the question.